# c++ - raw pointer to shared_ptr

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm using box2d and as you already may know, it holds a void* to an object which i can use as reference when collisions occur between different entities. Problem is that the original item is saved inside a shared_ptr since the ownership is unknown and different classes (example player class) can 'equip' another class (weapon).

I'm just wondering if its possible to put this pointer inside a shared_ptr and refer to the same object as the original one?

This is an example:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Environment>> listEnvironment;
listEnvironment.push_back(std::make_shared(new Weapon()));

//takes a void pointer
box2d->userId = listEnvironment.back().get();

//some shit happens somewhere else and collision occurs and I get pointer back from box2d's callback:

Environment* envPtr = static_cast<Environment*>(box2d->userId);
```

As you can see envPtr is going to cause trouble.
Is there a way to refer to the old smart-pointer and increase its reference value?

PS:

In actuality every class creates an box2d body which holds a 'this' pointer so i don't actually have the address to the smart-pointer either. The example above is kind narrowed down to give you a hint of the problem i'm facing.

Best regards
nilo

Comment: Why is `envPtr` likely to cause trouble? Is something going to try to delete it? Or is it going to live longer than the smart pointer that manages its life-time?

Comment: But the pointer will  remain valid as long as you don't delete it and as long as there exists a `shared_ptr` holding its value. If someone steals your weapon, are you going to hunt down every  `shared_ptr` and delete it?

Comment: Without knowing more about your architecture its impossible to say. But my gut feeling is using a raw pointer here is probably the right thing to do. However I am curious about your use of `shared_ptr` for a `Weapon`? Can two entities really be holding the same weapon at the same time?

Comment: No this problem is not as problematic as most people have with raw pointers. I can actually manage it kind of easily but its always nice to have a smart pointer take care of it and let the developer go full retard :D

Comment: Well the weapon is only one out of many entities in the game which all have different functionality. For instance a crate on collision can delete the ground while another crate can spawn a coin when it collides with the ground. So for instance if two crates hit the same ground object, one will try to delete it while the other one is going to use the pointer to see what it collided with in order to spawn the coin, which might result in a crash. I'm not having any problems at all so i guess the architecture is good but only wanted peoples input regarding raw pointers and shared_ptr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Environment` has [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)`<Environment>` as a parent class then, yes. Just call `envPtr->shared_from_this()`.

Comment: Looks like this can solve my problem. Going to experiment with it, cheers.